# User input in the correct formatting

Tags: python, user-input

I am attempting to ensure that a user inputs the correct hotel number. The formatting of the input should be 2 capitalized letters followed by a integer. I would like my code to provide an error message if the input is formatted incorrectly and re-prompt the user for the hotel number.

hotel = input("Please enter the hotel number: ")

Comment: I suggest looking up a regex tutorial.  This you get you to solve this problem, and many others in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished with regex. The statement would be `^[A-Z]{2}[0-9]$`.

**Explanation:**

`^` -- start of string
`[A-Z]` -- any capital letter
`{2}` -- two of the first
`[0-9]` -- any 1 digit number
`$` end of string

Your code:

```py
import re

rule = "^[A-Z]{2}[0-9]$"

x = None
hotel = None
while x == None:
    hotel = input("Please enter the hotel number: ")
    x = re.search(rule, hotel)
    if x == None:
        print("Error! Bad hotel number!")
```

Comment: Would this loop back to asking the user for input again?

Comment: @beginnerlearner456 I will make it do that.

Comment: @beginnerlearner456 updated. Should work now. Please upvote after u accept (you will have enough reputation to do so once you accept the answer.)